# Find the nine letter word

Tags: word, wordplay

> It is a 9 letter word.
>
> The 1st letter is a vowel.
>
> 4th, 5th and 7th letters are also vowel.
>
> 9th, 7th, 8th - number (contains a vowel).
>
> 6th, 7th, 8th - related to man.
>
> 8th, 7th, 4th - part of a human body.
>
> 9th, 4th, 1st - one of the drink.
>
> 2nd, 1st, 9th, 7th - used to go inside by this daily

Comment: Some criticism: All numbers contain vowels, so the fourth clue can be removed. "MEN" *means* "more than one man" - it's not "related to man", it *is* "man" (just more than one). You misspelled "knee", which is a fatal error in an already simple puzzle, and the other two clues have grammatical errors. I highly recommend double-checking your puzzles before posting them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> AGREEMENT

Explanation below

The 1st letter is a vowel.

> A

4th, 5th and 7th letters are also vowel.

> E, E and E

9th, 7th, 8th - number (contains a vowel).

> TEN

6th, 7th, 8th - related to man.

> MEN

8th, 7th, 4th - part of a human body.

> {K}NEE

9th, 4th, 1st - one of the drink.

> TEA

2nd, 1st, 9th, 7th - used to go inside by this daily

> GATE

And total 9 letters

Comment: I, ah, agree, but that body part seems to have lost a bit...

Comment: Yep, I also got stuck on the body part.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan And related to man : men. Ha!